# Modifying Vision Transformer (ViT) Model in timm for Custom Head in PyTorch

Tags: python, pytorch, computer-vision

I am working with the Vision Transformer (ViT) model using PyTorch and the timm library. My goal is to modify the ViT model to replace the default classification head with a custom head that takes the mean of all tokens and adds a new classification layer.

deafult summary of the ViT model in timm is ending like this:

```
       LayerNorm-247             [-1, 197, 768]           1,536
        Identity-248                  [-1, 768]               0
         Dropout-249                  [-1, 768]               0
          Linear-250                 [-1, 1000]         769,000
VisionTransformer-251                 [-1, 1000]               0
```

To remove the last layers so far I have coded:

```
class VisionTransformerWithoutHead(nn.Module):
    
    def __init__(self, model_name):
        super(VisionTransformerWithoutHead, self).__init__()

        # Load the ViT model
        vit_model = timm.create_model(model_name, pretrained=True)

        # Remove the final layers
        self.features = nn.Sequential(*list(vit_model.children())[:-1])

    def forward(self, x):
        # Forward pass through the modified model
        output = self.features(x)
        return output
```

Summary is now ending with:

```
       LayerNorm-247             [-1, 196, 768]           1,536
        Identity-248             [-1, 196, 768]               0
         Dropout-249             [-1, 196, 768]               0
```

It reduced the number of the tokens 197 to 196 and it seems to remove the class token.I would like to understand why this is happening and if there's a way to remove only the last layers while preserving the class token.

Answer (score 0):

```
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import timm

class CustomVisionTransformer(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, model_name, num_classes):
        super(CustomVisionTransformer, self).__init__()
        # Load the ViT model
        self.vit_model = timm.create_model(model_name, pretrained=True)
        
        # Remove the classifier head
        self.vit_model.head = nn.Identity()

        # Add a custom head
        # Assuming the dimension of the last layer's output is 768, adjust if necessary
        self.custom_head = nn.Linear(768, num_classes)

    def forward(self, x):
        # Forward pass through the base ViT model
        x = self.vit_model(x)

        # Take the mean of all tokens (including the class token)
        # You may need to adjust this depending on how you want to handle the class token
        x = torch.mean(x, dim=1)

        # Pass through the custom classification head
        x = self.custom_head(x)
        return x
```

Comment: using your code just  `self.vit_model.head = nn.Identity()` make the summary `LayerNorm-247             [-1, 197, 768]           1,536  
        Identity-248                  [-1, 768]               0  
         Dropout-249                  [-1, 768]               0  
        Identity-250                  [-1, 768]               0  
VisionTransformer-251                  [-1, 768]               0  
================================================================` there is only 1 token left in the end from 197 tokens.